# how to write sql query using substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some fields in a table `Employee`, with fields

```
empID,empName,empAddress,empCity...
```

And all the values of `empAddress` field contains like "ADR 250 Candy", "ADR 330 Simla, "ADR 220 Karty" and so on.

I want a query to list otr the address without the word 'ADR'.

Eg: I want to display the address like "250 Candy", "330 Simla", "220 Karty" ....

Please help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT SUBSTR(E.empAddress, 4) AS 'Address' FROM Employee E
```

If you want to skip the space character also replace `SUBSTR(E.empAddress, 4)` with `SUBSTR(E.empAddress, 5)`

Comment: The Query gives the correct answer. But while using the above(first one) i am getting the field name as SUBSTR(E.empAddress,4)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT EmpAddress = REPLACE(E.empAddress, 'ADR ', '') 
FROM Employee E
```

Comment: "try this" is not adequate explanation for an answer.  Please explain *why* this answers the question.  Code-only solutions are considered poor content on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi, could you please add some explanation to your code? This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Comment: well the REPLACE function does the normal replace in string job and it's a built-in SQL Server function, so i thought maybe it's self-explanatory and just put it sloppy out there. however, we have supposedly an Employee table and we're gonna replace the string ADDR with empty string in empAddress field.